# RTSP header malformed and different configuration

Tags: linux, window

Hi i have a camera with a not well formatted rtsp header

if i try with one ffmpeg it's work , with another two fails :/

What "config" make the windows version work ?

**[WORKING] win11**

```
C:\Users\spam>ffprobe rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor
ffprobe version 2022-09-19-git-4ba68639ca-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57. 36.102 / 57. 36.102
  libavcodec     59. 44.100 / 59. 44.100
  libavformat    59. 32.100 / 59. 32.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 49.100 /  8. 49.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
[h264 @ 00000232a28bc380] SEI type 240 size 512 truncated at 80
[h264 @ 00000232a28bc380] SEI type 240 size 512 truncated at 15
**Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s**
```

**[Error] on Ubuntu 20 wsl**

```
gigio2k@DESKTOP-2Q6HJQ4:~$ ffprobe -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor
ffprobe version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
**rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor: Invalid data found when processing input**
```

**[Error] on hassio**

```
bash-5.1# ffprobe -i rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor
ffprobe version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.1 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 20220219
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libpulse --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-lto --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-libaom --enable-libopus --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwebp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-vulkan --enable-libdrm --disable-debug
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
**rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.64:554/cam/realmonitor: Invalid data found when processing input**
```

What kind of config parameter let the first one works ?
My goal is make the other two ffmpeg working like the fisrt one!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Upgrade to the latest versions? Your Windows version is running with newer libs than the other 2 versinos.

Comment: are you talking about this libs ? 
  libavutil 
  libavcodec     
  libavformat    
  libavdevice    
  libavfilter     
  libswscale      
  libswresample  
  libpostproc  
wich one do you think is "the one" to update ? and how can i upgrade ? 

I already try the "apt update" on ffmpeg and the system say that i already had the newest available :/